# What does matrix representation and its linear operator have in common?

Tags: linear-algebra, big-list

I think it's beneficial to have a list of things a linear operator  $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ and its matrix representation $A=M(T,v)$ against any basis $v$ have in common.

What I have collected include: eigenvalues, trace, determinant, invertibility, and rank$(A)=\dim range(T)$. Are there anything else?

Thank you.

Comment: Adjoint, if $V$ has an inner product.

Comment: @eyeballfrog You also need $v$ to be orthonormal.

Comment: Do you mean what  the matrices $A$ and $PAP^{-1}$ have in common ? (where $PAP^{-1}$ is the matrix of $A$ in a non-canonical basis). The Jordan matrix $J$ is one possible representative of $\{ P A P^{-1} , P \in GL_n(\Bbb{C})\}$ so the Jordan normal form is all they have in common.

Comment: Every important property about a transformation is going to be shared by all matrix representations because they are just “pictures taken from different angles” of the same thing, sort of.

Comment: @rschwieb If basis is chosen differently in domain and codomain, you will find that a lot of things break down.

Comment: @DanielLi But why would anyone *do* that, if they truly can choose the basis?

Comment: @rschwieb Consider singular value decomposition which is based on two different basis in domain and codomain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following are common between a linear operator $T : V \to V$ and a matrix representation $M$ under a given a basis $\mathcal{B}$ for $V$:

- Eigenvalues
- Singular values
- Multiplicities (algebraic and geometric) of each eigenvalue
- Jordan Normal Forms
- Trace
- Determinant
- Characteristic polynomial
- Minimal polynomial
- Indeed, $\{p \in \Bbb{F}[x] : p(T) = 0\} = \{p \in \Bbb{F}[x] : p(M) = 0\}$
- Rank
- Nullity
- Invertibility

Even though not exactly a point of commonality, we also have the following correspondences:

- $v$ is a (generalised) eigenvector of $T$ if and only if $[v]_\mathcal{B}$ is a (generalised) eigenvector of $M$ (and all the obvious implications about (generalised) eigenspaces).
- The exponent of a generalised eigenvector $v$ with respect to $T$ is the same as $[v]_\mathcal{B}$ with respect to $M$.
- ($v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ is a Jordan basis for $T$ if and only if $([v_1]_\mathcal{B}, \ldots, [v_n]_\mathcal{B})$ is a Jordan basis for $M$.
- A vector $v$ belongs to the range of $T$ if and only if $[v]_\mathcal{B}$ belongs to the columnspace of $M$ (implying that their dimensions, i.e. ranks, are equal).
- The kernel of $T$ is the nullspace/kernel of $M$, expressed as coordinate column vectors with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ (they are eigenspaces corresponding to $0$ after all!).

There are  differences too between a  linear transformation $T$  and its matrix $M$.

- They are really objects in different structures. The former can be completely described using  only  the underlying vector space $V$, the latter on the pair $(V,B)$ where $B$ is a particular basis of $V$.
- Some properties are what we would call "basis-dependent", meaning that they change with respect to different bases. As an example, many (but not all) matrix norms are not really properties of the operators that generate these matrices, as different bases will generate matrices with a different norm.
- They support different uses and call upon different intuitions. The abstract transformation has a more geometric feel. The matrix is more algebraic. It's what you use to calculate examples.
- In some applications there is a natural basis that comes from the underlying problem domain. Then the matrix contains information you lose when you think only of the transformation. For example, consider the adjacency matrix of a graph.
- You choose one representation over the other to suit a particular purpose. When you interpret matrices as linear transformations it takes one line to prove   matrix multiplication is associative.  The direct proof requires painful manipulation of indices.
- Linear transformations make sense in more general contexts than matrices. The vector space $V$ need not be finite dimensional. It need not even be a vector space: a module over a ring will do. In these new contexts bases and matrices are harder to think about.

Comment: Answer is community wiki, so that people can add what they like to it.

Answer (score 3):

I think your question calls for a meta answer.

They have everything in common since they are different ways to describe the same thing. It's like asking what a parabola in the plane and its equation in the form $y = ax^2 + bx + c$ have in common.

Comment: I might just be pulling more "meta" where it doesn't belong, but I don't quite agree with the analogy. Parabolas in the usual orientations correspond uniquely to such quadratic equations, whereas one linear map will generally correspond to many (similar) matrices. If you insist on map-basis pairs then you get a many-to-one relationship instead. I think there is something non-trivial to be said on this topic, as evidenced by eyeballfrog's small omission in the comments under the question.

Comment: @TheoBendit I thought about that and decided to keep the analogy simpler even if less precise. Conic sections and quadratic curves might have been more accurate and less informative.